# Image library recommendations

Tags: image-processing

I'm looking for some image library that can work with multiple formats (jpg,gif,png), and is fast at displaying the images to the screen.

Also, it would be nice if I could specify only part of the image to render to the screen.

In the end I want to have lots of images on the screen that I can pan and zoom about.

This is for a personal project on my ppc powerbook, and I'd prefer if the library be in c++.

Comment: What language and platform are you targeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are also:

- Framewave based on [AMD Performance Library](http://framewave.sourceforge.net/) which provides signal and image processing features
- [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) multi-threaded derivative from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)

Check related questions

- [Fast Cross-Platform C/C++ Image Processing Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796364/fast-cross-platform-c-c-image-processing-libraries/)
- [Image processing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418631/image-processing-libraries)

Answer (score 3):

[FreeImage.](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/)

That's for loading.

For displaying, you can either use the FreeImage methods to make a bitmap that you can then display in some control (depending on your UI).

For the real hotness in display, you'll then want to use [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org).

Also, in the meantime, I've discovered [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/), which isn't a library so much as a framework for doing lots of common imaging applications and works in C++.

Answer (score 0):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) has libraries in several languages to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick seems to be the gold standard and is used in all sorts of places. What sort of environment are you working in -- Linux? Windows?

Comment: i seriously doubt he's running windows on a PPC laptop...