# Image Library Software

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, integration

I have a need for an Image Library within my organization and I was wondering if anyone knows of any that they could recommend. It will need to be able to integrate with any number of our own solutions (meaning it will have a set of services or APIs that one can use for integration).

Also I would be great if it had: facial recognition, geo-tagging, indexing of colors, people, places, photo content, (meaning it can detect the primary colors used in the photo, read content from the photo, like OCR, tell where the focus of the photo is), search by any of these (i.e. color, geo position, etc).

Basically a cross between, iPhoto (with its facial recognition, geo-tagging, etc) and iStockPhoto (with its color, content, focus placement detection, etc) for an Organization.

As you can imagine I would prefer not to have to build this myself.

Cheers
Anthony

- Note: I am more after a commercial piece of software that is an Image Library and does the above,  that allows for integration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used both [DotImage](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/DotImage/) and [LeadTools](http://www.leadtools.com/) to work with images...  they are the top .NET Imaging libraries out there (that I know of) and provide rich imaging functionality to develop applications.

Comment: At the time I chose LeadTools because the DotImage stuff was immature.  I liked the object model better for the DotImage stuff.  I think that it depends on what specific features you are going after.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about an image processing library or a program for storing images and with some extra features? In the first case, you might take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).

Answer (score 0):

Check similar questions

- [Fast Cross-Platform C/C++ Image Processing Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796364/fast-cross-platform-c-c-image-processing-libraries/)
- [Image processing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418631/image-processing-libraries)