# Programmatically add filter for real time video for iphone

Tags: iphone, video-processing

How to add filter effect for iphone camera, such as video blur or old 8mm effect?

Comment: Would the filters be added in real-time or after taking a photo?

Comment: the filter will be added in real-time

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply "filters" to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156872/how-to-apply-filters-to-avcapturevideopreviewlayer)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the current method to do this involves capturing frames from the camera as images using [AVCaptureSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html), also see [this technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html) from Apple. After starting an image stream, you'd have to modify the images before displaying them.

Comment: Personally I haven't tried that, but I would imagine that you would want to use an image processing library that lets you filter in whatever way you want. There is a good list of image processing cross-platform c/c++ libraries in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796364/fast-cross-platform-c-c-image-processing-libraries

Comment: @EricNondahl No, those are way too slow. You need to use OpenGL shaders.