# Retro, Lomo, Vignette filter in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, image, filter, vignette

I am trying to apply image filtering to images, like lomo, retro, vignette.

Can anyone show me some sample codes in C / C++? Or is there any ready-to-use libraries implementing image filtering?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate? -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796364/fast-cross-platform-c-c-image-processing-libraries

Comment: thanks for the libraries. Care to share the algorithm for lomo, retro, vignette in C or C++?

Comment: look for some step-by-step photoshop tutorials, then duplicate.

Comment: I am very new in image filtering and having hard time to translate the steps from Photoshop to codes like C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

[Opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome) is probably the easiest library to get started with, there are some [tutorials on image filtering](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc.html)