# Real time processing large images in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, image-processing, aforge

I have very large images (up to 12MPx) and I want to efficiently process them (panning, zooming, changing brightness and contrast), all must be done in WPF. I'm using AForge.NET library for image processing in unmanaged memory, it works good but only with small images. I'm looking for a good way to do all the transformations\filters and display them efficiently in real-time. How to do this?

Comment: I would do some tests with a native library such as OpenCV to check if what you want to do is theoretically possible on the hardware you have - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796364/fast-cross-platform-c-c-image-processing-libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no royal road. 12 Mega pixels are too many to process in real-time only by a CPU. Absolute lack of computational power is the real problem. I recommend you to use library on GPU, like DirectX or OpenCV_GPU.